# Is there a conformal diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $S^1\times S^2$ minus a point?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there a conformal diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^3$  and $S^1\times S^2$ minus a point on the $S^2$? I would have thought not, because the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is trivial, but that of $S^1\times S^2$ minus a point on the $S^2$ is not.

Comment: It's not clear if you mean $S^1 \times  (S^2 \setminus \{p\})$ or $S^1 \times S^2 \setminus \{(p, q)\}$. But in both cases the manifolds are not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I was thinking more about the first case - thanks. I was almost sure that my argument based on the fundamental groups was correct, but I just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 1):

You say yourself that the spaces have different fundamental groups, thus not homotopy equivalent, much less diffeomorphic. So, no.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my intuition.